# Preserving View Controller State

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to preserve the state of my view controller each time the user switches between view controllers. For example, on VC A I want to select a collection view cell and go to VC B and whatever is done in VC B (VC B contains selectable checklist items) I want saved so that when I go back to VC A and then again to VC B the state of the view controller is exactly how the user left it. I do not want the state to be saved in between app launches just when the user switches view controllers. I am not using segues as I know that reinstantiates the view controller each time, so this is my code so far. I have been searching for days and cannot figure how to solve this.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
        
    
    vc?.items = items[indexPath.row]
    vc?.images = images[indexPath.row]
    vc?.notes = notes[indexPath.row]
    vc?.textinfo = textinfo[indexPath.row]
    vc?.listItemArray = listItemArray[indexPath.row]
    
        
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Use callback to VC A from VC B while coming back from VC B and store the state of VC B in VC A again use the same state while pushing to VC B from VC A

Comment: @PrakashShaiva sorry I am new to swift,  how exactly would I do that?

Comment: This link may help you https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Comment: @PrakashShaiva everything that needs to be pass between the view controllers is passing correctly, it is just the preservation of the checklist selected states that is being reset, I am assuming because the view controller is being reinstantiated, not saved?